# Query from multiple threads on a database table

Tags: sql-server, database, multithreading, locking

I have a database table with thousands of entries. I have multiple worker threads which pick up one row at a time, does some work (takes roughly one second each). While picking up the row, each thread updates a flag on the database row (like a timestamp) so that the other threads do not pick it up. But the problem is that I end up in a scenario where multiple threads are picking up the same row.

My general question is that what general design approach should I follow here to ensure that each thread picks up unique rows and does their task independently.

Note : Multiple threads are running in parallel to hasten the processing of the database rows. So I would like to have a as small as possible critical segment or exclusive lock.

Just to give some context, below is the stored proc which picks up the rows from the table after it has updated the flag on the row. Please note that the stored proc is not compilable as I have removed unnecessary portions from it. But generally that's the structure of it.

The problem happens when multiple threads execute the stored proc in parallel. The change made by the update statement (note that the update is done after taking up a lock) in one thread is not visible to the other thread unless the transaction is committed. And as there is a SELECT statement (which takes around 50ms) between the UPDATE and the TRANSACTION COMMIT, on 20% cases the UPDATE statement in a thread picks up a row which has already been processed.

I hope I am clear enough here.

```
USE ['mydatabase']
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRequest] 
AS
BEGIN

    -- some variable declaration here

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- check if there are blocking rows in the request table
    -- FM: Remove records that don't qualify for operation.

    -- delete operation on the table to remove rows we don't want to process
    delete FROM request where somecondition = 1


    -- Identify the requests to process
    DECLARE @TmpTableVar table(TmpRequestId int NULL);

    UPDATE TOP(1) request 
        WITH (ROWLOCK)
           SET Lock = DateAdd(mi, 5, GETDATE()) 
        OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @TmpTableVar
          FROM request tur
         WHERE (Lock IS NULL OR GETDATE() > Lock)   -- not locked or lock expired
           AND GETDATE() > NextRetry -- next in the queue   

        IF(@@RowCount = 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN
        END

    select @RequestID = TmpRequestId from @TmpTableVar

    -- Get details about the request that has been just updated
    SELECT      somerows
    FROM        request
    WHERE       somecondition = 1

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the columns of table `request`?

Comment: @IgorPaiva I updated the columns in the question

Answer (score 1):

The analog of a critical section in SQL Server is [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql), which is simple to use.  Alternatively you can SELECT the row to update with (UPDLOCK,READPAST,ROWLOCK) table hints.  Both of these require a multi-statement transaction to control the duration of the exclusive locking.

Answer (score 0):

You need start a `transaction isolation level` on sql for isolation your line, but this can impact on your performance.

Look the sample:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

GO

SELECT ID, NAME, FLAG FROM SAMPLE_TABLE WHERE FLAG=0

GO

UPDATE SAMPLE_TABLE SET FLAG=1 WHERE ID=1

GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Finishing, not exist a better way for use isolation level. You need analyze the positive and negative point for each level isolation and test your system performance.

More information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql

http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-server-isolation-levels-by-example

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Comment: This does not work for me. If i set a higher isolation level then I am basically negating the advantage of having multiple threads. I am looking at locking at as much lower granular level as possible.